# Delphi XE - [DCC Error] : E2004 Identifier redeclared: 'System'

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I do not understand why this error occurs...Is this a bug in XE, or is something wrong in the IDE settings?

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `System` unit is automatically used by all other units in a Delphi program. So you cannot use it again. Simply remove `System` from your `uses` clause.

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Programs_and_Units#Unit_References_and_the_Uses_Clause) states:

> The `System` unit and the `SysInit` unit are used automatically by every application and cannot be listed explicitly in the `uses` clause.

Comment: No, is not...I am accepting now the answer. (at this moment)123k reputation on your side, 7+ votes on the question, and being the only answer to this question, I believe it is natural to accept it...+1 and thank you

Comment: I wouldn't let the reputation sway you. The documentation I link to should be what makes your mind up. Thanks!

Comment: Lol, I just edited a file of JVCL installer to remove an error